# how i can can get the id weird issue it is in wicket 1.4

Tags: wicket

I am facing a weird issue it is in wicket 1.4.

We have a ReservationDateField which is extended from Datefield.

The problem is that in datefield, I have an input Datetext field and it has an id generated by wicket, which I need to change.

I need to change the markupId for the input tag; please see the photo:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="arena-reservation-from">
                        <div class="arena-form-content" wicket:id="validFromDateContainer">
                            <label class="arena-field" wicket:for="validFromDate"><wicket:message key="ReservationValidFrom.label"/></label>
                            <label class="arena-input-text" wicket:id="validFromDate"></label>
                            <p id="arena-add-reservation-validFromDate-error-msg" class="arena-input-error-msg" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </div>
```

The java is here :

```
    private void addFromDateFieldContainer() {
    DateField field = new ReservationDateField("validFromDate");
    WebMarkupContainer container = new 
         WebMarkupContainer("validFromDateContainer");
    container.add(field);
    container.setVisible(configParams.isShowReservationFromDate());
    add(container);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel)`

```
DateField field = new ReservationDateField("validFromDate") {

  @Override
  protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
    DateTextField dateTextField = DateTextField.forShortStyle(id, dateFieldModel);
    dateTextField.setMarkupId("mySpecialId");
    return dateTextField;
  }
```

Comment: I have a question here, 
why we write the line :
    DateTextField dateTextField = DateTextField.forShortStyle(id, dateFieldModel);

Comment: This is the default implementation. I just copied it. Please accept the answer!